# How can I periodically update the XML Importer in Quartz Composer?

Tags: xml, quartz-composer

I'm new to Quartz Composer so please excuse if this is obvious ... 
I have a Quartz Composer composition here that imports a XML file. I'd like it to update the imported file lets say every minute. I found the "update signal" input and tried to built a periodic signal to feed into it, but no success. (This is the Periodic Signal I used: http://quartzcompositions.com/phpBB2/mediawiki/index.php?title=Periodic_Signal&redirect=no)
Any help is appreciated! This is a for an animated layer in BoinxTV by the way. If anyone of you is familiar with that ...
Thanks,
thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an instance of the built-in `LFO` (`Wave Generator` in Lion) patch
2. Set the Type to Square
3. Set the Period to 60 seconds
4. Connect the output to the `Update Signal` input on the `XML Importer` patch.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The problem I had was that they used _TypeFilePath for the XML Importer which apparently copies the XML file into the application bundle. I removed that and now the display is properly updated.